# I can't understand what happening after running function execve() in my code?

Tags: c

I write shell in Unix, and, when I run `ls | wc > file` it works good, but when I run `ls > file` my program hangs and does not react to anything. The result of command `ls` writing in the file, and all subsequent functions are processed, and output to the terminal, but the program does not respond to keyboard input. At the beginning of the program, I disconnect 
`termios.c_lflag = (termios.c_lflag ^ ICANON) ^ ECHO;
tcsetattr(2, TCSANOW, &termios);` but it should not be cause, in case `ls | wc > file` all going good.

In this function we take as fd, `fd[1] = open(file, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666)` and `fd[0] = 0` or `fd[0] = in`, where `in = fd[1]` from previous `pipe(fd)` if it were before.
I can't understand, why did this happened? Help me please)
And one more question, why did latter "C" didn't write both to the terminal and to a file, after `execve`? Latter "A" write into the terminal, "B" in the begin of file, both "C" lost, and "D" into the terminal.

`void   command_to_file(char *f_pth, char **mas, char **env, int *fd)`

```
pid_t   pid;

pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{
    write(1, "A", 1);
    ft_putendl(mas[0]);
    dup2(fd[0], 0);
    dup2(fd[1], 1);
    write(1, "B", 1);
    if (execve(f_pth, mas, env) < 0)
    {
        write(2, "error execve", 12);
        return ;
    }
    write(1, "C", 1);
    write(2, "C", 1);
    close(fd[0]);
}
else
{
    wait(0);
    write(1, "D", 1);
    close(fd[1]);
}
```

Comment: You should compile your code with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and **use the debugger `gdb`** (so take some time to learn how to use it). You may want to also use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html). You probably should not care about `termios` at first.

Comment: Supposing that it succeeds, **nothing** happens after `execve()` in your code.  `execve()` *replaces* your program with a different one.

Comment: You may want to study the source code of existing shells

Comment: Note that `execve()` replaces the current process unless it fails.  Normally, you should exit if the `execve()` fails — returning is unlikely to be correct.  The pair of `write()` statements after the `execve()` will never, ever be executed — either the process is replaced or the return in the `if` clause has been executed.  You should probably close both `fd[0]` and `fd[1]` after the calls to `dup2()` and before the `execve()`.  **Rule of thumb**: If you use `dup()` or `dup2()` to make a file descriptor into one of the standard channels, you should close the original file descriptor.

Comment: Also, in the event that the forked process's `execve()` fails, it is `highly` unlikely that you want it to perform a `return`.  Usually, the only reasonable thing to do in that circumstance is to call `_Exit()`.

Comment: Thank you for answer) I use flags (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`) termios i use to intercept keyboard signals, to make move by history with arrows, and move on my string in terminal. On that moment I didn't know anything about `strace()`.  Sorry for my english, it not so good)

Comment: About `dup()` i didn't knew, and some things about `execve()`, thank you, I will read about this)